# How to fix media screen break problems

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari, media-queries

I have been researching for a few days now and I have not been able to come up with a solution to my problem.

Now, for a mobile screen break I have decided to use (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px). On the desktop browsers (chrome, firefox, IE8, Safari); however, when I put the files on the server and try to bring the site up on my iPhone 4s, the screen breaks do not work and all my background images disappear.

Here is my desktop css (there are seven sections, but I am going to list two, because each section is identical - except for the background picture):

```
#home{width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    background: url(../images/landingPage.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;}

#about{width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    background: url(../images/about.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;}
```

Here is the css for the media screen breaks:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px){

    #home{background-image: url(../images/landingPageMobile.jpg);}

    #about{background-image: url(../images/aboutMobile.png);}

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on a fix or if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I can confirm that your code works on iOS: http://jsfiddle.net/meub/zEV9X/3/. Any way you can provide more code? Are both css snippets in the same file?

Comment: Yes, they are both on the same stylesheet. What other code would you like to see?

Comment: Maybe just a link to your live site?

Answer (score 0):

u need this...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Comment: Why?  Explain please!